# Selecting literal values from Wikidata federated query service using RDFLib

Tags: python, sparql, rdflib, wikidata-query-service

I'm trying to get external identifiers for an entity in Wikidata. Using the following query, I can get the literal values (`_value`) and optionally formatted URLs (`value`) for Q2409 on the Wikidata Query Service site.

*[Load in Wikidata Query Service](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fproperty%20%3F_value%20%3Fvalue%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fproperty%20wikibase%3ApropertyType%20wikibase%3AExternalId%20.%0A%20%20%3Fproperty%20wikibase%3AdirectClaim%20%3Fpropertyclaim%20.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fproperty%20wdt%3AP1630%20%3FformatterURL%20.%20%7D%0A%20%20wd%3AQ2409%20%3Fpropertyclaim%20%3F_value%20.%0A%20%20BIND%28IF%28BOUND%28%3FformatterURL%29%2C%20IRI%28REPLACE%28%3FformatterURL%2C%20%22%5C%5C%24%22%2C%20%3F_value%29%29%20%2C%20%3F_value%29%20AS%20%3Fvalue%29%0A%7D)*

```
SELECT ?property ?_value ?value
WHERE {
  ?property wikibase:propertyType wikibase:ExternalId .
  ?property wikibase:directClaim ?propertyclaim .
  OPTIONAL { ?property wdt:P1630 ?formatterURL . }
  wd:Q2409 ?propertyclaim ?_value .
  BIND(IF(BOUND(?formatterURL), IRI(REPLACE(?formatterURL, "\\$", ?_value)) , ?_value) AS ?value)
}
```

Using RDFLib, I'm writing the same query, but with a federated service.

```py
from rdflib import Graph
from rdflib.plugins.sparql import prepareQuery

g = Graph()
q = prepareQuery(r"""
  PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
  PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
  PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>

  SELECT ?property ?_value ?value
  WHERE {
    SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql> {
      ?property wikibase:propertyType wikibase:ExternalId .
      ?property wikibase:directClaim ?propertyclaim .
      OPTIONAL { ?property wdt:P1630 ?formatterURL . }
      wd:Q2409 ?propertyclaim ?_value .
      BIND(IF(BOUND(?formatterURL), IRI(REPLACE(?formatterURL, "\\$", ?_value)) , ?_value) AS ?value)
    }
  }
""")

for row in g.query(q, DEBUG=True):
  print(row)
```

With this, I'm getting the URLs as `URIRef` objects. But, instead of `Literal` for the literal values, I'm getting `None`.

*First 6 lines of output:*

```
(rdflib.term.URIRef('http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P232'), None, None)
(rdflib.term.URIRef('http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P657'), None, None)
(rdflib.term.URIRef('http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P6366'), None, None)
(rdflib.term.URIRef('http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P1296'), None, rdflib.term.URIRef('https://www.enciclopedia.cat/EC-GEC-01407541.xml'))
(rdflib.term.URIRef('http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P486'), None, rdflib.term.URIRef('https://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/D0068511.html'))
(rdflib.term.URIRef('http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P7033'), None, rdflib.term.URIRef('http://vocabulary.curriculum.edu.au/scot/5001.html'))
```

What am I missing for the literal values? I'm having trouble figuring out why I'm getting `None` instead of the values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if all of the features of `SERVICE` calls are fully implemented in RDFLib.

I would get this working with a 'normal' call the Wikidata SPARQL endpoint using either RDFLib's [SPARQLWrapper](https://github.com/RDFLib/sparqlwrapper) library or the general-purpose web request Python libraries `requests` or `httpx` first. If that all works, you could then try again with the `SERVICE` request but you likely won't need it.